# Как узнать ID только что добавленного элемента в SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

В учебных целях реализую веб-сервис, позволяющий посчитать MD5-хеш от файла, расположенного в сети Интернет. Требуется такой api, что пользователь задает ссылку на файл и свой email. Сервер должен дать в ответ id задачи (файл будет закачиваться в фоне). Получается мне нужно дать id будущей записи в БД. Как это сделать? Заранее благодарю!

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    # строка вида "email=user@example.com&url=http://site.com/file.txt"
    data = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")

    ddata = {}
    for elem in data.split('&'):
        pair = elem.split('=')
        ddata.update({pair[0]: pair[1]})

    task = Task(**ddata, status='running')
    db.session.add(task)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'ok', 201 # Task.query.get(???)
```

Здесь сама модель Task:

```
class Task(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    md5 = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

id давать будущей записи в БД не нужно - все добавит автоматом 
вот у Вас

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```